# Damage modifier on Priest Staves

Tags: age-of-empires-online

Some priest Holy Staves have the +damage modifier on them. This appears quite often. Since priests can't attack, what's the point of having this modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priests are useful when dealing with wild animals. The damage modifier comes into effect here.

See the [general tips section on the fanpage](http://aoeo.heavengames.com/strategy/quests/greek-quests/spread-the-word/) and [this discussion in the forums.](http://aoeo.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/forums/display.cgi?action=ct&f=2,144,,10)

Comment: You deserve more points than that sir. I've always thought of the damage modifier for priests as useless or extremely situational and you just confirmed my suspicion. However when the Celts become available, the damage modifier would be useful on the Druids which do damage like a standard infantry unit.